# Is an H1 tag that contains a style block with CSS as well as an image with alt text Google-friendly?

Tags: seo, html, search-engines

Here is how my website's H1 tag shows up in the Moz tool (or any other SEO tool I used so far):

[image]

The website is build through Shopify platform and Shopify says it's perfectly fine but I have my doubts, especially that H1 tags *of other pages* show up normally in Moz, not as a line of code

Anyone run into this issue before? I'm by no means an expert coder, that's why I ask because it raised some red flags for me. It would be pretty bad if Shopify's styles influence the SEO in a bad way for the MAIN page of the website.

Comment: I'm not sure why H1 (which should be simply: Olympian Bitcoin) appears as a piece of code here. Can someone more experienced take a look at the source of the website here and inspect whether there is something wrong with the h1 tag: https://olympianbitcoin.store/

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

That's not appropriate. Your H1 has to be text containing your main keywords for good SEO. 
Those codes displaying there now will be considered text by your shopify analysis, of course, they are.
But they will not be meaningful to Google search engines. Thus, affecting your SEO drastically.

You can set the image logo with the  tag as you have done but consider removing the H1 tags that is wrapping round the  tag.
If you want the logo to replace your H1, you could consider hiding your H1 text.

To do this, this post will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665037/replacing-h1-text-with-a-logo-image-best-method-for-seo-and-accessibility

Answer (score 0):

In the **[Search Engine Optimization (SEO) Starter Guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184)** **==> Optimize your content**, Google clearly recommends not doing this:

> Avoid: 
>   ...**Embedding text in images** and videos for textual content:
>   users may want to copy and paste the text and search engines can't
>   read it.

Comment: But that's if you make a jpg with your brand's motto, for example (rather than simply write it as a text). Google can't read it so it's not recommended but some people may want to do it to avoid duplicate text content. Anyway, that's something else entirely. My question was about h1: whether Google will read it correctly when it's formatted like this